# PyDev Unit Test for Django 1.6 and South: OperationalError: no such table:

Tags: django, eclipse, unit-testing, pydev, django-south

I am having problem with PyDev Unit Test when South is in my INSTALLED_APPS.
The error returned is: OperationalError: no such table: lists_list

If I comment South in INSTALLED_APPS or if I ran tests from shell with: python manage.py test, everything works fine.

Seems that there is a problem with creating test DB when running test from PyDev Unit Test and having South.

**My environment is:**
Win 8
Python 2.7
Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2
PyDev for Eclipse 3.8.0.201409251235
Django (1.6)
mock (1.0.1)
pytz (2014.7)
selenium (2.43.0)
South (1.0)

Here are the details:

**settings.py**

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'lists',
    'south',
)
...
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),

    }
}


SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False # To disable migrations and use syncdb instead
SKIP_SOUTH_TESTS = True
```

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from lists.models import Item, List

class NewListTest(TestCase):

def test_saving_a_POST_request(self):
    self.client.post(
        '/lists/new',
        data={'item_text': 'A new list item'}
    )
    self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
    new_item = Item.objects.first()
    self.assertEqual(new_item.text, 'A new list item')
```

**Result:**

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

test_saving_a_POST_request (lists.tests.NewListTest) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_saving_a_POST_request (lists.tests.NewListTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\learn\TDD_py2_dj16\superlists\lists\tests.py", line 30, in test_saving_a_POST_request
    data={'item_text': 'A new list item'}
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 483, in post
    response = super(Client, self).post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 302, in post
    return self.request(**r)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 444, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\learn\TDD_py2_dj16\superlists\lists\views.py", line 14, in new_list
    list_ = List.objects.create()
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 157, in create
    return self.get_queryset().create(**kwargs)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 319, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1511, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 898, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\virt_envs\django16test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 450, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
OperationalError: no such table: lists_list

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.017s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Any ideas?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just curious: What happens if you set `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE` to `True` ?

Comment: @herbertp.  

If True then South migrations are used during creation of test DB. So, if there are many migrations (and many tables) it will take some time.  
If False, Django syncdb is used. Like when db is building from scratch.  
But testing in Eclipse does not work either way, unless South is commented in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: And you are absolutely sure, that you are using Django 1.6 and not 1.7?

Comment: @herbertp. Of course! It is virtualenv, set up like described above. If it was 1.7 it would not be possible to make any migrations with south (it would rise an error...)